# Create .NET project using Salesforce Partner WSDL SERVICE reference

Tags: .net, vb.net, web-services, wsdl, salesforce

I am trying to consume a Salesforce Partner WSDL using Visual Studio.  But I want to use it as a Service Reference instead of Web Reference because Web Reference using .NET 2.0 and I am having intermittent problems with that.  Specifically, when I call a method called DescribesObjects, I receive an error of "Error in XML Document {1, 65851}.  I suspect it's because .NET 2.0 only allows 64K size XML files for responses.

But when I create the Service Reference instead, I can't figure out how to Login using the different reference because the methods are all different.  Has anyone else every come across this?

If you have a solution to the XML document problem, that would be even better.

Thanx!

Comment: I found AN answer though it's not the preferred answer.  

It appears that Service Reference supports a binding attribute called MaxReceivedBufferSize that you can add to your app.config bindings (not your login) of whatever size you need.  BUT, it only supports it with .NET Framework 3.0 or better.

And, logging into the Service Reference is tougher, so I created an instead of the Web Reference too, and when I need the DescribeSObjects, I call a Service Reference instead where I set the applicable objects needed as below so that it softly binds to the web reference login.

Comment: Best of both worlds with 1 login:

                Dim SFSR As New SFPartnerServRef.SessionHeader()
                Dim epAddr As New System.ServiceModel.EndpointAddress(oBinding.Url)
                Dim oBind As New SFPartnerServRef.SoapClient("Soap", epAddr)
                Dim oLogon As New SFPartnerServRef.LoginResult

                Dim SFSObj As New SFPartnerServRef.DescribeSObjectResult
                SFSR.sessionId = oBinding.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId
                oLogon.serverUrl = oBinding.Url
                oLogon.sessionId = oBinding.SessionHeaderValue.sessionId